# kubernetes pod trying to connect itself and fails because http://localhost:<port>

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

We have helm based k8s application where one of the pod (named "auth") Has code that call itself to do CRUD operation for resetting password.

Since it's calling itself, This operation is using endpoint URL http://localhost:8081/API/authorizations

***Issue:***
  When deploying same application at on-premises k8s cluster auth pod is not able to connect itself.

**Error:**
  `{"api":"external","component":"auth","delay":900000000,"error":"Post http://localhost:8081/api/authorizations: dial tcp 10.250.44.31:8081: connect: connection refused","insecureSkipVerify":false,"message":"Request failed, retrying","method":"POST","requestID":"fb9475e8-bcf9-4924-8339-d3d21922f357","severity":"debug","timestamp":"2020-02-10T11:54:29Z","url":"http://localhost:8081/api/authorizations"}`

Note: 10.250.44.31:8081 is cluster endpoint IP address

***Expected behavior***:
  When running this application at **AWS eks or azure aks**, **it's working** fine with desired operation.

***Question:***

1) is it expected behavior for pod to connect to k8s master server ha proxy IP when using localhost endpoint inside pod?

2) for AWS eks and azure aks it's referring to pod URL only, so does it mean that our cluster network has to be troubleshooted for solving this issue?

Thanks with added ∆ points in advance..

Comment: Are you using any service mesh?

Comment: What is the networking plugin that you are using?

Comment: Not using service mesh... Deployment of app is in helm chart.

Comment: Please, provide more details regarding your cluster. How it was deployed, what cni are you using, it's on bare metal or on a cloud provider?

Comment: Cluster is deployed using rancher on VM cluster. It uses flannel and coredns.

Answer (score 1):

1) is it expected behavior for pod to connect to k8s master server ha proxy IP when using localhost endpoint inside pod?

> NO, It is not expected to connect to Master API Server for localhost communication

2) for AWS eks and azure aks it's referring to pod URL only, so does it mean that our cluster network has to be troubleshooted for solving this issue?

Exec into the pod

> kubectl exec -it "pod-name" -n "namespace" bash

Once inside the pod, check if some process is listening on port `8081`

> ps -ef | grep "8081"

If you find the desired process running and listening on the port, curl the endpoint and check whether you are getting the response back or not

> curl -v http://localhost:8081/API/authorizations

Comment: Thanks Shawshank,  pod do not have bash so we can not do exec..  To test service is running theory, we created another pod and exec to bash..    Getting 200 success when using curl http://<service name.>:8081/api/authorizations ..  Not able to find why localhost is not running but service name from outside is working..

Comment: Need more info on this. Can you please attach the /etc/hosts file of the affected pod. In the meantime if there is only one "auth" pod running, then instead of making a call to localhost you can use <auth-pod-service-name>:<port>/API/authorizations as well. Its a hack not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

what's the contents of `/etc/hosts` on the image being run? I'm guessing that it's misconfigured or missing, so the container process instead of getting proper IP of `localhost` from there, asks nameserver for it. probably your api server is also your cluster DNS and when asked about localhost, it responds with its own IP.

as a quick workaround you can change your program to use `127.0.0.1` directly instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check on /etc/hosts...  it's standard application that works fine at 100s of other cloud based k8s clusters like eks and aks. I feel solving this cluster problem can really be permanent thing :)

Comment: @TejasSheth yes, so my theory is that it is a combination of 2 things: broken `/etc/hosts` **AND** nameserver on master responding incorrectly to query about `localhost`. the DNSes on other environments may be better configured to reply with `127.0.0.1` instead of their own IP.